# Standard set of Generators

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

A standard set of generators for a semisimple Lie algebra $ L $ is defined as:

{${x_\alpha}, {y_\alpha}, {h_\alpha} $}

Where:
$ x_\alpha \in L_\alpha, $
$ y_\alpha \in L_{-\alpha}, $
$ [{x_\alpha}{y_{\alpha}}]=h_\alpha $
$\alpha \in \Delta $

> Wouldn't the standard set of generators require the $ x_\alpha $, $ y_\alpha $, and $ h_\alpha $ of all simple roots of base $\Delta $ if there are is than 1 simple root in $\Delta $ ?

Help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The set of generators is $\{x_\alpha,y_\alpha,h_\alpha: \alpha\in \Delta\}$. So it has $3|\Delta|$ elements. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system_of_a_semi-simple_Lie_algebra#Associated_semi-simple_Lie_algebra

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  I was confused because in  the book I'm reading (Humphreys' intro to Lie Algebra and Rep theory) it seemed like he was just considering 1 simple root in a base of size $ n $, which made no sense. In addition could we just consider the $ x_\alpha $ and $ y_\alpha$, $\forall$  $\alpha \in \Delta $, and forget the $ h_\alpha$'s. It seem redundent to count the $ h $'s since the $ x, y $'s make them by the bracket.

Comment: You're welcome! Indeed, the set of just the $x_\alpha$ and $y_\alpha$ will generate the Lie algebra. The nice thing about the complete set of $x_\alpha,y_\alpha,h_\alpha$ is that we can give an elegant presentation of the Lie algebra using them, namely the Serre relations.